# Assign a list to the value of one element of another list

Tags: r

I want to make the value of a list element equal to another list, like so...

```
list_one <- as.list(c(A = NA, B = NA))
list_two <- as.list(c(C = 4, D = 5))

list_one['A'] <- list_two
```

This is throwing the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In list_one["A"] <- list_two :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

How do I properly make `list_two` a sub-list of `list_one` so that I don't get this warning?

Comment: Why in the world is this being downvoted? It's a clearly asked question, showing reproducible code of what's already been tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[[` instead of `[`

```
list_one[['A']] <- list_two
```

Comment: This works. What's the difference between the double and single brackets?

Comment: You can read their documentation by entering `?\`[\`` in the R console. In a nutshell, `[` returns or substitutes sub-*list*, while `[[` returns or substitutes a single item of the list.